# How to format Duration string?

Tags: java

I have a string with value as "3D7H40M20S"
Which should be converted as 3 Days 7 Hours 40 Minutes and 20 Seconds".
Here is what I tried so far:

```
        BindingContainer bindings = BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    AttributeBinding attr = (AttributeBinding)bindings.getControlBinding("ScreeningSLAWaitTimeDuration");
    scrSlaWaitDur = (String)attr.getInputValue();
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------SCREENING SLA WAIT DURATION---------------"+scrSlaWaitDur);
    scrSlaWaitDur = scrSlaWaitDur.substring(2, scrSlaWaitDur.length());
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------SUBSTRING--------------------"+scrSlaWaitDur);
    int dIndex = scrSlaWaitDur.indexOf("D");
    System.out.println("*******************************************INDEX OF D**********************************"+dIndex);
    if(dIndex != -1){
        String newDur = scrSlaWaitDur.substring(0, dIndex)+" days "+scrSlaWaitDur.substring(dIndex+1);
        int mIndex = scrSlaWaitDur.lastIndexOf("M");
        String newDur2 = scrSlaWaitDur.substring(0, mIndex)+" minute "+scrSlaWaitDur.substring(mIndex+1);
        int sIndex = newDur2.lastIndexOf("S");
        String newDur3 = newDur2.substring(0,sIndex)+" second";
        scrSlaWaitDur = newDur3;
        return scrSlaWaitDur;
    }
```

I know this is quite tiresome and quite lengthy.
Can I achieve the requirement in a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pragmatic approach would be replacing the unit tokens:

```
return scrSlaWaitDur.replace("D", " Days ").replace("H", " Hours ").replace("M", " Minutes ").replace("S", " Seconds");
```

Output:

```
3 Days 7 Hours 40 Minutes 20 Seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring() without index(), i.e.:

```
String result = 
scrSlaWaitDur.replace("D"," Days ").replace("H"," Hours ").replace("M"," Minutes ").replace("S"," Seconds");
```

But I'm sure someone will come up with a fency regex solution. ;-)